# Import single variable from another Makefile

Tags: android, variables, makefile

I need to import only one variable from another makefile. I can't just include the other makefile as some of the variables defined in the other makefile mustn't be imported. I thought using grep would be a solution but I couldn't figure out how exactly. The variable's called USE_SU and it can be found in the file

$(ANDROID_BUILD_TOP)/device/*/$(BS_BUILD)/BoardConfig.mk

How can I import this variable into my current makefile?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The proper solution would be to create a third makefile, which just defines the variable, and have the original makefile, and your new makefile include that one.  If, however, the other makefile is a third party makefile (you can't modify it), then you could use the technique described here: https://blog.melski.net/2010/11/30/makefile-hacks-print-the-value-of-any-variable/

You create `print.mak`:

```
print-%:
    @echo '$*=$($*)'
```

and then in your new makefile you do:

```
 ORIG_MAKEFILE=$(ANDROID_BUILD_TOP)/device/*/$(BS_BUILD)/BoardConfig.mk

 VAR:=$(shell $(MAKE) -f $(ORIG_MAKEFILE) -f print.mak print-VAR)
```